# How to expose the inheritance_column in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, sti

I need to expose the inheritance_column in the JSON response so that I can retrieve it in my frontend (Angular) application. How can I make it real?

I have searched a lot for an answer to this question but I haven't found it!

In my case scenario, I have User that can be an Admin, an Employee or a Customer. The only difference is that Customer has two more fields than Admin and Employee. That's why I decided to implement STI. Feel free to tell me if I made a bad choice about it.

Example of my user_serializer.rb:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :type
end
```

[image]

My user.rb is in /models

My users_controllers.rb is in controllers/api/v1/

UPDATE:

My controller:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < Api::V1::BaseApiController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # some methods...

  def show
    user = User.find(params[:id])

    if user.present?
      render json: { data: user }, status: 200
    else
      head 404
    end
  end

  # some methods...

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :id,
      :name,
      :email,
      :password, :password_confirmation,
      :registration,
      :cpf,
      :landline, :cellphone, :whatsapp,
      :simple_address,
      :public_agency_id,
      :public_office_id,
      :type
    )
  end
end
```

My model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

  # belongs_to :address
  attr_accessor :skip_password_validation

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :type, presence: true

  scope :admins, -> { where(type: 'Admin') }
  scope :employees, -> { where(type: 'Employee') }
  scope :customers, -> { where(type: 'Customer') }

  # CALLBACKS
  before_validation :generate_uuid!
  before_create :downcase_email

  def password_required?
    return false if skip_password_validation
    super
  end

  def token_validation_response
    {
      id: id,
      email: email,
      name: name,
      surname: surname,
      cpf: cpf,
      landline: landline,
      cellphone: cellphone,
      whatsapp: whatsapp,
      simple_address: simple_address,
      created_at: created_at,
      updated_at: updated_at,
      type: type
    }
  end

  private

  def generate_uuid!
    self.uid = SecureRandom.uuid if self.uid.blank?
  end

  def downcase_email
    self.email = self.email.delete(' ').downcase
  end
end
```

Response object sample:
[image: Response sample]

And about the config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb, there is no such file in my project.

Comment: Are you just using the default inheritance column ‘type’?  Or did you define a unique column?  Why don’t you just add ‘type’ to your .jbuilder view output?

Comment: Hi, Andew. 
Yes, I'm using the default comun :type. I've never used jbuilder, I'm using the gem active_model_serializers, but It doesn't work, my user_serializer.rb is simply ignored.

Comment: can you post your controller and model as well?

Comment: Also, do you have a `config/initializers/active_model_serializer.rb`?  If so, please post that too

Comment: Lastly, can you output the results of your JSON api call in question that is missing the type field?  that might help diagnose if ActiveModelSerializer is being used to render the JSON.

Comment: Hi, andrew21. I just added in the last edit the resources/examples you asked for. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information on your controller, model, initizializers, and JSON output to accurately diagnose this problem.  but I'll take a shot in the dark that may be helpful.

Overall, it looks like you may not be loading your UserSerializer.  I would suggest moving it into the root of serializers and get it working there:  Then if you want to move it to api/v1 for some reason you can focus on the namespacing issue that may be hanging things up.

```
# app/serializers/user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :type
end
```

If this works, then a call such as `get /users/:id` should return something like:

```
{ "id": 1, "name":"Bill Gates", "email":"bigcheese@microsoft.com", "type": "Employee" }
```

You may need to update your Application controller as well for serialization:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Serialization

  # ...
end
```

A couple resources that might be helpful:

1. [Codeship tutorial](https://blog.codeship.com/building-a-json-api-with-rails-5/)
2. [Building the perfect API](https://sourcey.com/building-the-prefect-rails-5-api-only-app/)

Comment: I added the line include ActionController::Serialization, but nothing has changed =/